# How to publish a C# windows application with database and Crystal Reports?

Tags: c#, database, publish, crystal-reports-2008

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 and I want to publish a C# application which contains a SQL Server database and Crystal Reports. I have tried deploying the project with setup project and using SQL Server 2005 and Crystal Reports as prerequisites but it still doesn't work.

Comment: What is the problem you encountered?

Answer (score 0):

make sure to install the Crystal reports runtime on the client's machine, then the reports will work as well. If there is no crystal reports installed they will not work on client's machine.

Cheers

Comment: @SAMARTH AND @ WAQAR-  i am amking an c# windows app which includes database and crystal reports. i want to install this application on a system that doesnt have sqlsever and crystal reports installed. i want to install them when the setup of my application runs. alos i want to make this application Windows XP compatible. PS i am using windows 7